# Условие при запросе sql

Tags: sql, php, mysql

Можно ли одним запросом выполнить такое действие: если запить уже есть в таблице, то изменить её, а если записи нет, то добавить её

Comment: [да][1]


  [1]: http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?43

Comment: mysql <> oracle

Comment: что же это зачит?

Comment: если я правильно понял, это значит, что в mySql это (возможно) работать не будет

Comment: попробовать стоит.

Comment: ну, во-первых, стоит попробовать найти документацию по mysql. вы же могли и по transacsql ссылку дать, тоже можно было бы попробовать, только смысл? во-вторых, для mysql есть специальный механизм, ifthenelse не нужен.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите с запросом к базе данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296846/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление записей в бд](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448488/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1):

Можно:

```
INSERT INTO `tab` (`uniquefield1`, `field2`)
VALUES( 10, 'запись с 10 номером')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`field2` = 'запись с 10 номером уже была';
```

Для uniquefield1 должен быть создан уникальный индекс.

Comment: Как код определяет что запись уже была? Что если уникальность записи надо проверять по двум полям?

Comment: По ключу. А чем Вам не нравится ключ, который включает два поля?

Comment: Просто второе поле не совсем годится для того чтоб вешать на него ключ

Comment: ключ создается по нескольким полям (если у вас комбинация уникальна):

    create unique index fio on users (lastname, firstname, middlename);
    insert into users (lastname, firstname, middlename, age)
      values ('Иванов','Иван','Иваныч', 42)
    on duplicate key update
      age = 42