# Как обновить существующую запись в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть данный код но в нём проблема:

```
$odd = "1";
$eff = "1";
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`eff`, `odd`) VALUES ('$eff','$odd')");
```

Подскажите как сделать проверку на запись, если `eff` уже такой в базе есть то он обновляет у него строку `odd` а если нету `eff` он создаёт

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление записей в бд](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448488/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4)

Comment: @Visman, зачем более старый вопрос объявлять дубликатом более нового?

Comment: @TagirValeev, потому что тут автор вопроса не отметил ответ как правильный, а там ответ помечен верным. + не только я так делаю. Уже несколько таких редиректов подтверждал от других пользователей.

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения команды поле eff должно быть уникальным ключом:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`eff`, `odd`) VALUES ('$eff','$odd') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `test` set `odd` = '$odd'
```

Дополнение:

```
# Проверяем есть ли поле с нужным значением.
$q = query("select ogg from `test` where `eff` = '".$eff."'");
if($q){
    # Если есть обновляем
    query("update `test` set `odd` = '".$odd."' where `eff` = '".$eff."'");
}
else{
    # Если нету делаем вставку
    query("INSERT INTO `test` (`eff`, `odd`) VALUES ('".$eff."','".$odd."')");
};
```

Comment: Ну а индекс что бы сравнивать ? и если есть такой как он будет обновлять

Comment: INSERT INTO *** ON DUPLICATE KEY - в этой строке пытается вставить данные, если не получается то выполняет UPDATE, изменяя ячейку, которую находит по уникальному индексу. В вашем случае это `eff`

Comment: Хотелось бы не в 1 строку код

Comment: В смысле не в одну строку? Человек написал вам запрос, вставте его вместо своего в mysql_query()

Comment: Чем больше кода, тем больше время выполнения. Но если требуется не одна строка смотрите ответ, дополнил.