# Добавить значение в строку даже при ее отсутствии

Tags: mysql

Обновляю значение в таблице базы данных - необходимо прибавить единицу к значению поля `field` определенного пользователя:

```
$query = 'UPDATE table_users '
        .'SET field = field + ' . $field_inc . ' '
        .'WHERE id = ' . $user_id;
```

Проблема в том, что эта таблица связана с основной таблицей пользователей,и  в ней присутствуют записи не о каждом пользователе. То есть, если мы решим увеличить значение `field` для пользователя, которого нет в этой таблице, то ничего не произойдет. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в случае отсутствия записи о пользователе в таблицу записывалось не `field + $field_inc`, а просто `$field_inc`.

Comment: вам нужен `insert... on duplicate key update...`

Comment: Вам нужен т.н. upsert, в случае c mysql - [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите с запросом к базе данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296846/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление записей в бд](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448488/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4)