# Как при вставке данных добавить только записи с уникальным значением столбца, а если значение существует обновить запись?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

имеется таблица со следующей структурой:

```
-----------------------------
ID     IP          Timestamp
-----------------------------
1      127.0.0.1   1111111111
2      127.0.0.1   1111111112
```

Нужно сделать следующее: в таблицу не должны записываться новые записи, у которых `IP` соответствует `IP` в таблице, *а должен лишь обновиться `Timestamp` в таблице*, иначе - добавляется новая запись с новым `IP`

```
-----------------------------
ID     IP          Timestamp
-----------------------------
1      127.0.0.1   1111111112
```

пробовал ставить `индекс->unique`, но тогда не обновляется `Timestamp`

как это дело реализовать не отправляя 2 запроса?

Comment: Я бы сделал так: 1. $ip = '127.2.3.0"; 2. Ищем в таблице этот ip. 2. Если  не находим идет запрос на добавление в базу. Если находим обновляем Timestamp

Comment: @Денис не отправляя 2 запроса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите с запросом к базе данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296846/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На столбце `ip` предлагаю поставить уникальный ключ, на `id` поставить AUTO_INCREMENT ([но лучше](http://habrahabr.ru/post/156489/) этот столбец убрать вообще) и использовать запрос вида `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
insert into `table_name` (`ip`, `last_modified`) 
       values ($ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) 
       on duplicate key update `last_modified`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: @maschine, столбец `Timestamp` зря так назвали.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сделал так:

- убрал столбец id
- сделал бы столбец ip primary key
- использовал бы запрос REPLACE INTO `table` VALUES ('%ip%',
  %timestamp%)

Как-то так.

Answer (score -1):

можно реализовать через триггер  на вставку after или before

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ip_insert ON table_ip
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
begin 
if exists(select 1 from table_ip where table_ip.ip=inserted.ip) 
  update table_ip set Timestamp=99999 where table_ip.ip=inserted.ip
else 
  insert into table_ip selec ID,IP,Timestamp from inserted
end
```